# What does Swift dynamicType return?

Tags: swift, dynamic, swift2, metaprogramming, metaclass

Consider the example below:

[image]

```
class P {}
class C: P {}
let i: P = C()

let iDT = i.dynamicType
let CS = C.self

iDT == CS
iDT === CS

iDT.dynamicType == CS.dynamicType

iDT.dynamicType
CS.dynamicType
```

The question is: Why is `iDT.dynamicType` `P.Type.Type`?
I would expect it to be `C.Type.Type`.

Answer (score 2):

This would be simpler:

```
class A {}
class B:A {}
let i: A = B()
i.dynamicType
i.dynamicType.dynamicType
```

So we may deduce that `i.dynamicType` is the type `i` really is (polymorphically), but `i.dynamicType.dynamicType` is the type `i` is typed as. Note that it isn't A; it's A.Type, a metatype. The notion of `dynamicType.dynamicType` is sort of an edge case, so this is presumably an implementation detail.

It's interesting to do all this in the REPL:

```
  1> class A {}
  2> class B:A {}
  3> let i : A = B()
i: B = {
  __lldb_expr_1.A = {}
}
  4> i.dynamicType
$R0: A.Type = __lldb_expr_3.B
  5> i.dynamicType.dynamicType
$R1: A.Type.Type = metatype for __lldb_expr_1.A
```

Comment: This doesn't answer me anything why `iDT === CS` is true but `iDT.dynamicType == CS.dynamicType` is false, it looks like compiler bug to me.

Comment: @BryanChen Agree! I am also wondering the same thing. `iDT` and `CS` seem identical. If there is a bug here, probably it's a bug with the `===` operator rather than with the `dynamicType` property.

Comment: I would recommend doing all this in the REPL, not a mere playground. It is much more informative about how Swift thinks.